# How many `select into` command can be used in the `executeBatch` results of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask how many `select into` can be placed in `result = statement.executeBatch()` of Apache IoTDB? Are there any relevant restrictions for the number of `select into` used, or what should I need to know to use the combination of these two commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache IoTDB, `executebatch` cannot be used to execute `select into`. `executebatch` is used to execute `update` type statements, such as `delete`, `create`, `insert`, etc., but `select into` is essentially a query statement and will return a result set. The type of these two commands are not the same, so it is recommended not to use them like you said (in a mixed way).